# Orthonormalization of a set of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, projection

I know of the commands Orthogonalize[] and Normalize, but how can I combine them into one command that its output will be an orthonormalized list of the input vecotrs?

Thanks in advance.
P.S
How to orthonormalize w.r.t the trace inner product for matrices?

Comment: `Orthogonalize[{vec1, vec2, ...}, Method -> "Householder"]` will always yield an orthonormal set.

Comment: @J.M.and if I want to orthonormalize w.r.t the trace inner product?

Comment: ...then you should have mentioned that in your question to begin with.

Comment: @J.M. then I am asking in the comments, and I add it to my original post.

Comment: For further clarity, how does your reference define the trace inner product of two vectors? How is it different from `Dot[]`?

Comment: It's $<A,B> = Tr[A.Transpose[B]]$ for two matrices, A and B.

Answer (score 1):

Use COMPOSITION functions will help.

Try the following code~

```
Orthonormalize[list_]:=Normalize/@Orthogonalize@list
```

Can this help?